# Installing Ubuntu on Miix320

Tags: windows, lenovo, tablet

Can some one help me how to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Miix 320. Windows is struggling to support and its keeps getting hung. Ubuntu definetely fits well in this kind of situation and need someone's knowledge here to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the documentation from the official [tutorials.ubuntu.com](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)

And then ask us if you have any issue while installing.